# VBA nonsense pointing at the wrong sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Some strange things are happening to me in VBA. Somedays I am coding and everything works fine, then I go out of the code and the next day when I want to run the exact same code from the day before the code doesn't go into the loop, but jumps directly into end sub().

I tried to use the Activate sheet function, it seemed to work for 10 seconds and then afterwards suddenly it didn't work again which means my code didn't go into the loop again. The reason why I was using Activate sheet function was because I was afraid that my code was pointing at the wrong excel file / sheet. I have a lot of excel files and all of the sheets in those excel files are called Sheet1 could that create problems??

To give you a concrecte example, say I day one use the following code to loop through a column:

```
Sub stuff()

' Sheet1.Activate

lngLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set sheet1ArkRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z" & lngLastRow)
Set offsheetarkrng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L5")

Dim i As Integer

For i = 3 To sheet1ArkRng.Rows.Count
    
    sheet1VirkNavn = sheet1ArkRng.Cells(RowIndex:=i, ColumnIndex:="C").Value

Next i

End Sub
```

Then day 1 everything works fine and the variable sheet1VirkNavn shows me the value of the rows in column C. It can be seen when I debug.

Then day 2 once I debug the exact same code from the exact same file it goes to

"For i = 3 To sheet1ArkRng.Rows.Count"

and then jumps directly into

End sub

Comment: Does your processed sheet have values in column A:A? Maybe not...? If yes, place the next code line `Debug.Print sheet1ArkRng.address`, immediately after `Set sheet1ArkRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z" & lngLastRow)`. What does it return?

Comment: On the line `lngLastRow = ...`, you use `Rows.Count` without a worksheet which means it counts the rows in the active worksheet, not `Sheet1`. Is that expected?

Comment: @Wander Nauta: Being in the same workbook, any sheet has the same number of rows...

Comment: @FaneDuru: So what you are telling me is that lngLastRow shouldn't use A if all rows in column A are empty?

Comment: Is the correct workbook active when you run the code? `Worksheets("Sheet1")` will just look at whatever book is currently active.

Comment: Yes. It counts the rows of A:A column... You should use a column being relevant from this point of view.

Comment: If all rows in column A are empty it will return 1 and your loop will not do anything (`For i = 3 to 1`).

Comment: If you are dealing with lots of workbooks, you should specify not only the Worksheet, but also the workbook. Your code is accessing `Sheet1`  of the ActiveWorkbook - maybe not what you expect.

Comment: @FunThomas the thing about not leaving Column A empty seems to be working! This has been bothering me on and off for 2-3 months now... Thanks a lot. The reason why I was using A was just to put something in there, such that I could define lngLastRow. Is there another way I can define lngLastRow such that it won't bother me in the future?

Comment: [5 Different Ways to Find The Last Row or Last Column Using VBA](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you're running exactly the same code against exactly the same data and getting different results, you should probably call an exorcist because your workbook is clearly possessed. OTOH, if you're running exactly the same code against different data and getting different results, the problem is the incorrect assumptions you're making about the format of the data. The fastest way to identify the problem is to step through the code in debug mode and examine the values of the variables.

Comment: Your next issue will be an overflow problem when using `Integer` instead of `Long`.  If the number is greater than 32,767.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

I've learned what

> lngLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

means. Now it all makes sense. If you're using the above code to loop through last row you should use the same letter for the column you want to loop through...

So the case was my code wasn't getting into the loop simply because my "A" column was empty.